# how to serve static files in golang

Tags: go

I'm tryng to make a simply webserver in golang, but i cannot figured how to serve static css files.
Here is the structure of mi project:

```
project folder
->static
  ->templates
    ->index.gohtml
  ->styles
    ->style.css
```

in my template i have this simple line of html: `<link href="/styles/styles.css" type="text/css">`
in the main.go i have this:

```
http.Handle("/styles", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/styles")))
...
//show the backend homepage that refers to index.gohtml
http.HandleFunc("/backend/home", handler)
```

Comment: *i cannot figured how to serve static css files*. What's the problem, exactly? Indicating where your Go source files are located in your project folder structure would likely help.

Answer (score 4):

Right now when they hit `/styles`, it will try and access `./static/styles/styles`, so you generally strip the prefix like so:

```
http.Handle("/styles/", http.StripPrefix("/styles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/styles"))))
```

See https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#example-FileServer-StripPrefix

Comment: nope, nothing change, i try to put a 

body {
  background-color: black;
} and nothing shows up

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser console?  is the CSS file loading at all or are you getting a 404?

Comment: no error on a console, no error 404, no nothing, and yet nothing styled on a webpage, i try to clean the cache and nothing changed

Comment: i have to change the header in this:

...<style>
        @import url("/styles/style.css");
</style>
</header>
and now I see it the request, but still empty response

Answer (score 1):

I figured out (just for for luck)

I have to put this on the main.go

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/styles"))
http.Handle("/styles/", http.StripPrefix("/styles", fs))
```

and this on the header:

```
<style>
    @import url("/styles/style.css");
</style>
```

otherwise it doesn't work